# Incremental Builds - Determining Inputs/Outputs in Existing Tasks

Tags: gradle, input, output, incremental-build

I'm trying to determine inputs and outputs of previously written custom tasks on a very large project, so that I can formally define them for incremental building. My understanding is that if I formally define them as inputs and outputs, then their last modified time stamps will be checked on build, to determine if they need to be rebuilt (if no changes since last build, they're skipped to save time).

Am I correct in my understanding of how this works, in general? And what should I be looking for to determine inputs and outputs? There are many instances of "copy from " "into "; it seems that those would be good candidates for inputs (the former) and outputs (the latter)? I've read the Gradle docs on this but think I could use a little advice from the masses. Thanks, all.